# Create object at runtime which have the same internal contents

Tags: scala, generics, return-current-type

I am performing a repetitive task of creating a object that has same internal contents and hence thought of creating a generic method that would help me achieve this.

The internal object is as follows

```
case class Data(value: Int)
```

I have a base trait as follows

```
trait Base
```

There are a couple of classes that extend this trait

```
case class A(data: Data) extends Base
case class B(data: Data) extends Base
case class C(data: Data) extends Base
```

The generic method that I am trying to write to create the object

```
def getObject[T <: Base](data: Data, t: T) = {
  T(data)
}
```

However, while trying to do so, I get a compile-time error saying that

```
Cannot resolve symbol T
```

Can you please let me know what I am missing in this method implementation. 
Note:- This is a very simplistic implementation of what I am trying to do in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [typeclass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59827312/5205022) solution for compile-time safety

```
final case class Data(value: Int)
final case class A(data: Data)
final case class B(data: Data)
final case class C(data: Data)

trait BaseFactory[T] {
  def apply(data: Data): T
}

object BaseFactory {
  def apply[T](data: Data)(implicit ev: BaseFactory[T]): T = ev.apply(data)
  implicit val aBaseFactory: BaseFactory[A] = (data: Data) => A(data)
  implicit val bBaseFactory: BaseFactory[B] = (data: Data) => B(data)
  implicit val cBaseFactory: BaseFactory[C] = (data: Data) => C(data)
}

val data = Data(42)
BaseFactory[A](data)   // res0: A = A(Data(42))
BaseFactory[B](data)   // res1: B = B(Data(42)) 
BaseFactory[C](data)   // res2: C = C(Data(42))
```

Answer (score 4):

Due to [type-erasure](https://blog.knoldus.com/type-erasure-in-scala/), you can't use generic type to create a new instance of an object.

You could use `ClassTag` to capture a class of T at runtime:

```
case class Data(value: Int)

trait Base

case class A(data: Data) extends Base
case class B(data: Data) extends Base
case class C(data: Data) extends Base

def getObject[T <: Base](data: Data)(implicit ct: ClassTag[T]): T = 
  ct.runtimeClass.getDeclaredConstructors.head.newInstance(data).asInstanceOf[T]


val a: A = getObject[A](Data(1))
val b: B = getObject[B](Data(2))
val c: C = getObject[C](Data(3))
```

As cchantep noticed, it has a drawback, that if your case class doesn't have a constructor with single argument `Data`, this function will fail at runtime.

Comment: Or a factory type class that would avoid unsafe runtime reflection

Comment: @Krzysztof Atłasik Thanks for the answer. Upvoted it but would prefer a typeclass implementation as it is type safe