# Accessing nested type parameters in Dotty Scala

Tags: scala, class, monads, typeclass, dotty

I would like to do something like this with the new Scala Dotty compiler:

```
trait Monad[M[A]] (underlyingValue:A) {
  def bind[A, B](f: A => M[B]): M[B]
}
```

or at least

```
class Monad[M[A]] (underlyingValue:A) {
  def bind[A, B](f: A => M[B]): M[B]
}
```

but the compiler complains that Not found: type A

is there someway to access the type parameter of a type parameter? Or something with the same end result but done differently?

I know that you can create a Monad like here: https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/type-classes.html
but having a Monad class would allow me to declare a class a Monad in the same place it is defined, and would also make more sense to my stylistically.

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226852/discussion-on-question-by-ameltz-accessing-nested-type-parameters-in-dotty-scala).

Comment: I wonder if match types could be used for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, The following solution fulfills the criteria I had in mind:

```
trait Monad[F[_], A](underlyingValue: A) {

  def flatMap[B](f: A => F[B]):F[B]

}
```

And usage would look like:

```
class Opt[A](underlyingValue: A) extends Monad[Opt, A](underlyingValue: A) {
   def flatMap[B](f: A => Opt[B]):Opt[B] = {
     ...
   }
}
```

While it does require two type parameters, the type parameter "A" is not repeated twice, and as such there's no logic duplication.

Comment: Cool it worked for you, that encoding is called **F-Bounded** Polymorphism, and has some known limitations / problems, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813323/advantages-of-f-bounded-polymorphism-over-typeclass-for-return-current-type-prob) for more information. I also, still do not see how would this work for things like **List** or **IO** _(or even the same `None` of **Option**)_, but we will see how to goes in the long run.

Comment: That's interesting, checking it out. Yeah with None it becomes problematic. It works with null but even I don't that's not a good solution.  The issue is constructor cannot act as pure since a constructor must exist for all types, but for example no branch of pure yields a None. The tweak I'm going with to to create pure as its own function. Thank you for the link, I will definitely check it out.