# Scala inherited type doesn't satisfy parent type requirement

Tags: scala, generics, types

Have been using Scala for a while, and hoping to get into domain modeling using type constraints. In the following code, I am trying to design a domain. Excuse the cryptic classnames, wanted to focus on the specific problem I am facing at hand.

Here is the code:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

class ClassTypeTest
{
    trait TSM
    {
        def fit[T <: TSM](): FR[T]
    }

    abstract class FM extends TSM{}

    trait MP[T <: TSM]
    {
        def name: String
    }

    trait FiM[T <: TSM]
    {
        val fittedParams = mutable.HashMap[String, MP[T]]()
    }

    class FR[T <: TSM](fm: FiM[T])


    // Now define classes related to SMA
    //===================================
    abstract class SMAP extends MP[SMA]
    class SMAO(n: String) extends SMAP
    {
        override def name = n
    }
    class SMAM(smao: SMAO) extends FiM[SMA]
    {
        fittedParams(smao.name) = smao
    }

    class SMA extends FM
    {
        override def fit[SMA]() =
        {
            val fim = new SMAM(new SMAO("x"))
            //*******************************
            // Following line shows the error:
            // Error:(40, 25) type mismatch;
            // found   : ClassTypeTest.this.SMAM
            // required: ClassTypeTest.this.FiM[SMA]
            //            new FR[SMA](fim)
            //*******************************************
            new FR[SMA](fim)
        }
    }
}
```

I am defining SMAM as `extends FiM[SMA]`, so why is the compiler complaining about `Type mismatch. Required FiM[SMA], found: SMAM`. Have I ill-defined one of the type parameters or constraints?

I am trying to constrain the type of fit method, and the FR object to one of the subclasses of TSM. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    trait TSM
    {
        def fit[T <: TSM](): FR[T]
    }
```

This defines a trait with a method `fit` that for *any* type `T` returns an instance of `FR[T]`

```
    class SMA extends TSM 
    {
        override def fit[SMA]() =
        {
            val fim = new SMAM(new SMAO("x"))
            new FR[SMA](fim)
        }
    }
```

This overrides method `fit` defined in the trait. `SMA` in method definition is a *type parameter*, not a reference to the class name. You can (probably, should) replace it with `T`, it'll be equivalent, but a bit less confusing:

```
   override def fit[T <: TSM](): FR[T] = new FR(new SMAM(new SMAO("x")))
```

This will give you a more descriptive error - something to the effect that you are trying to return `FR[SMA]` where `FR[T]` is expected.

The bottom line is you cannot make a method in subclass less "generic" than it is declared in a superclass. To better understand why that is the case, consider this:

```
   abstract class Foo extends TSM 

   val sma: TSM = new SMA()
   val foo: FR[Foo] = sma.fit[Foo]()
```

This *should* work: `sma` is an instance of `TSM`, and `TSM.fit` is supposed to work for any type parameter which is a subclass of `TSM`, which `Foo` clearly is.
But your `SMA.fit` as written can only return `FR[SMA]`, so the snippet above would not work if it was allowed.

How to fix this?
Well, that depends on what you actually *want*. One possibility is to parametrize the trait itself rather than the method:

```
    trait TSM[T <: TSM[_]] {
       def fit(): FR[T] 
    }

    class SMA extends TSM[SMA]
    {
        override def fit() = new FR(new SMAM(new SMAO("x")))        
    }
```

Comment: This is the F-bounds approach, right? Was reading up a bit on this based on comment from @HTNW earlier (https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html), and looks like there are some gotchas in terms for holes, but still very usable solution.

Comment: @SamikR yeah that is an **F-Bound**, take a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813323/advantages-of-f-bounded-polymorphism-over-typeclass-for-return-current-type-prob) for other alternatives and their trade-offs.

Answer (score 3):

> I am defining `SMAM` as `extends FiM[SMA]`, so why is the compiler complaining about `Type mismatch. Required FiM[SMA], found: SMAM.`

`SMA` in `def fit[SMA]() = ...` in

```
class SMA extends FM
{
    override def fit[SMA]() =
    {
        val fim = new SMAM(new SMAO("x"))
        new FR[SMA](fim)
    }
}
```

is a type parameter. It's arbitrary type, not the class `SMA` (the type parameter `SMA` hid class `SMA`). You could use arbitrary identifier here, e.g. `T`

```
class SMA extends FM
{
    override def fit[T]() =
    {
        val fim = new SMAM(new SMAO("x"))
        new FR[T](fim)
    }
}
```

So I guess the error

```
type mismatch;
 found   : SMAM
 required: FiM[T]
```

is clear now.

Comment: Do you think OP intended `T` in `TSM#fit` to be a abstract member type (or just F-bounded generic parameter to the class)?

Comment: @HTNW I guess in order to answer this question we should understand OP's business logic :)

Comment: Hi - thanks for the quick response. @HTNW: I guess I do not understand enough the difference between these two cases that you mention, but the business requirement was that I wanted the FR object to be defined with one of the subclasses of TSM.

Comment: @DmytroMitin: I think I understand what you are saying: I was mistaking SMA to be the class type, but actually it is an arbitrary type, which is what you show by replacing SMA with T. How should I proceed then to get to what I want to achieve as mentioned above?