# Can I use typeclasses to get non-mixing of subclasses, shared implementation of combine, and also return subclass type?

Tags: scala, typeclass

Cats and Dogs are both Pets, and thus have an age. I would like to define a `chooseOldest` method that, given either two cats or two dogs, will choose whichever pet is oldest, but which will refuse to choose when both a cat *and* a dog are presented.

Semigroups implemented with typeclasses seems to get me 90% of the way there, but I can't figure out if it is possible to define `chooseOldest` *once*; theoretically since all `Pet`s have an age, it should not need to be implemented for each `Pet`, but practically speaking I can't figure out how to define it only once while still returning the type of the subclass and retaining the "cats and dogs don't mix" rule:

```scala
trait Pet {
  def age: Int

  // When implementation is shared, it *doesn't* return the subclass type
  def _chooseOldest(rhs: Pet): Pet = if (age > rhs.age) this else rhs
}

case class Dog(age: Int) extends Pet
case class Cat(age: Int) extends Pet

trait Semigroup[A] {
  def chooseOldest(lhs: A, rhs: A): A
}

// When the implementation returns the subclass type, it can't be shared
implicit val dogSemigroup = new Semigroup[Dog] {
  override def chooseOldest(lhs: Dog, rhs: Dog): Dog = if (lhs.age > rhs.age) lhs else rhs
}

implicit val catSemigroup = new Semigroup[Cat] {
  override def chooseOldest(lhs: Cat, rhs: Cat): Cat = if (lhs.age > rhs.age) lhs else rhs
}

def chooseGeneric[P <: Pet](p1: P, p2: P)(implicit ev: Semigroup[P]): P = ev.chooseOldest(p1, p2)

def canChooseDogs(d1: Dog, d2: Dog)(implicit ev: Semigroup[Dog]): Dog = chooseGeneric(d1, d2)(ev)
def canChooseCats(c1: Cat, c2: Cat)(implicit ev: Semigroup[Cat]): Cat = chooseGeneric(c1, c2)(ev)

// Appropriately errors because there is no Semigroup[Pet]
def cantMixCatsAndDogs(c: Cat, d: Dog)(implicit ev: Semigroup[Pet]): Pet = chooseGeneric(c, d)(ev)
```

If I can't figure this out, I'll try [F-bounded polymorphism next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813323/advantages-of-f-bounded-polymorphism-over-typeclass-for-return-current-type-prob), but I suspect that there is a solution here that I'm missing simply because this is my first foray into type classes.

Is it possible to implement the 3 given requirements using typeclasses?

1. Cats and dogs can't be "combined"
2. `chooseOldest` has a single implementation
3. There exists a `chooseOldest` which returns the *subclass type*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```scala
sealed trait Pet {
  def age: Int
}
object Pet {
  final case class Dog(age: Int) extends Pet
  final case class Cat(age: Int) extends Pet

  sealed trait ChooseOldest[P <: Pet] {
    def apply(p1: P, p2: P): P
  }
  object ChooseOldest {
    given instance[P <: Pet](using NotGiven[P =:= Pet]): ChooseOldest[P] with
      override def apply(p1: P, p2: P): P =
        if (p1.age > p2.age) p1 else p2
  }
  
  extension [P <: Pet](self: P)(using ev: ChooseOldest[P])
    def chooseOldest(other: P): P =
      ev(self, other)
}
```

Note that the `NotGiven[P =:= Pet]` is what ensures that there won't be an instance that allows mixing types.

Comment: You're using Scala 3 syntax here, but does this rely on any features that are only available in 3? Ie, is it possible for me to translate this to Scala 2 myself?

Comment: @CoryKlein `NotGiven` is not part of the **Scala 2** stdlib, you have three options: 1) If you have **Shapeless** in scope then you can use `=:!=` which is equivalent to `NotGiven[=:=]` 2) Reimplement `=:!=`, is not much code: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/main/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/package.scala#L41 3) Not make `instance` implicit and rather make it `private` then manually create `implicit final val dogInstance: ChooseOldest[Dog] = instance` and repeat that for all cases, at least the logic is shared but the definitions have to be repeated.